# How to unmap keys in fish?

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, fish

I want to unmap (unbind) certain keys such as Up, Down, Left, Right, Page Up, Page Down, Home, End specifically in the [fish](/questions/tagged/fish) shell.

I guess I have to use the `bind` command in the `.config/fish/fish.config` file, but I am not sure how.

Comment: For interest, how come?

Comment: @Zanchey to "lock" (and never deviate from) vim style (key bindings, navigation, modes) activated in fish by me :)

Comment: @Chinggis6: Note that fish 2.4.0 made the vi-bindings more vi-y. 2.3.X just added them on top of the normal bindings (i.e. vi-mode inherited from emacs-mode), while 2.4.0 only shares a few explicit things that don't really _conflict_ with vi-style text editing.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to define a custom `fish_user_key_bindings` function with the appropriate `bind --erase` statements, then save that function with `funcsave` or by editing `~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_keybindings.fish` directly.

For example:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind --erase --key up
    bind --erase --key down
    # and so on
end

funcsave fish_user_key_bindings
```

Note that some terminals don't send the terminal codes that their terminal description files say they do - you may need to use `fish_key_reader` (introduced in 2.3.1) to confirm the exact binding you need to erase.